# Detect background image size and apply div height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a series of `<div>` containers with a background image and info panel.

On the desktop version, the background image uses `background-size: cover;` to fill the width and height of the `<div>`.

When switching to mobile, I have changed the background size to `background-size: contain;`. This is because I don't want any cropping to occur and for it to act more like an inline image.

As the parent `<div>` has a fixed height, extra white space is being created.

Is it possible with CSS or JavaScript to calculate the background image size and apply it to the div height? I would like to do this on the resize of the viewport and avoid refreshing.

I'm aiming for support in IE9+.

Here's the basic markup:

```css
.row {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Background image */
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-position: center !important;
  background-size: cover !important;
}

.info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 1.5em;
  background-color: #dedede;
  color: #000;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .row {
    background-size: contain !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="background: url('http://www.babyclothingzone.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/kitten_field_jump.jpeg')">

  <div class="info">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Some text goes here</p>
  </div>
  
</div>

<div class="row" style="background: url('http://www.babyclothingzone.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/kitten_field_jump.jpeg')">

  <div class="info">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Some text goes here</p>
  </div>
  
</div>

<div class="row" style="background: url('http://www.babyclothingzone.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/kitten_field_jump.jpeg')">

  <div class="info">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Some text goes here</p>
  </div>
  
</div>

<div class="row" style="background: url('http://www.babyclothingzone.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/kitten_field_jump.jpeg')">

  <div class="info">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Some text goes here</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Easiest way is to inside each div.info add the image as a <img>-tag with visibility:hidden; then height:auto; on the div.info.

More markup, but no JS required

Comment: This is really nice solution. Could I just use a transparent png with width and height? I guess it also means I can give it an alt tag.

Comment: Can you set this as your answer @ninja? It's the solution I ended up using.

Answer (score 0):

You can create image tag with source image set the height and get the width:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.row').each(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    var backgroundImage = self.css('background-image');
    if (backgroundImage.match(/url/)) {
      var img = backgroundImage.match(/url\(['"]?(.*)['"]?\)/)[1];
      $('<img src="' + img + '"/>').appendTo('body').load(function() {
        var img = $(this);
        img.height(self.height());
        self.width(img.width());
        img.remove();
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.row {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 1.5em;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Background image */
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-position: center !important;
  background-size: cover !important;
}

.info {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 1.5em;
  background-color: #dedede;
  color: #000;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .row {
    background-size: contain !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" style="background: url('http://www.babyclothingzone.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/kitten_field_jump.jpeg')">

  <div class="info">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Some text goes here</p>
  </div>
  
</div>

<div class="row" style="background: url('http://www.babyclothingzone.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/kitten_field_jump.jpeg')">

  <div class="info">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Some text goes here</p>
  </div>
  
</div>

<div class="row" style="background: url('http://www.babyclothingzone.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/kitten_field_jump.jpeg')">

  <div class="info">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Some text goes here</p>
  </div>
  
</div>

<div class="row" style="background: url('http://www.babyclothingzone.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/kitten_field_jump.jpeg')">

  <div class="info">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>Some text goes here</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the url as a data attribute.

```
<div class="row js-background" data-background="http://www.babyclothingzone.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/kitten_field_jump.jpeg" style="background: url('http://www.babyclothingzone.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/kitten_field_jump.jpeg')">
```

And then programmatically get the image and check the dimensions using Javascript...

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  alert(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
}
img.src = document.getElementByClassName('js-background').getAttribute('background');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made an example with one div, but you can use it in a `each` loop to get all imagens:

```
// get the div, it can be in a each loop
var div = $('.row').first();
var imgSrc = $(div).css('background-image').replace(/url\(['"]?(.*)['"]?\)/gi, '$1').split(',')[0].replace('"','');
// load a image with src of background
var image = new Image();
image.src = imgSrc;
// wait a while to load image and get the size
image.onload = function() {
    console.log(this.width);
    console.log(this.height);
}
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/as3c2naz/

Hope it helps.